# flexible plastic hose coming out of toilet tank

Tags: plumbing

What is the purpose of an additional flex tube coming into or out of the toilet tank?

It is not the braided inlet hose into the tank.

Comment: What is it connected to, or where does it go? Could you perhaps post pictures?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to know what you mean; would you edit  in a picture? Thanks.

Comment: If the end of it is above the (normal) cistern fill level then it is probably the *overflow pipe*. A picture would help to confirm that.